# Куки без сервера?

Tags: cookie, javascript

Здравствуйте. Озадачили тут, нужно сделать обратный отсчет на html-страницах, но без сервера. Будет пара страниц из архива. Открывают первую - старт с 30 минут до 0. 
Думал на JS и куках сделать. 
В голову приходит проблема домена: нормально ли браузер на следующий страницах позволит их считать? И вообще, может есть более элегантное решение? (Ну в голову еще приходил Web-Storage из HTML5, но могут попадаться старые браузеры).

Comment: @ReinRaus, интересный вариант и похоже единственный остается.  
Преобразуйте комментарий в ответ - помечу как правильный.

Comment: Вы Mosaic Netscape поддерживаете ещё? localStorage отлично себе работает с IE8, не работает до сих пор только в Opera Mini, да и не должно. А как вы поборете людей, которые JS выключили? :) Или браузеры без поддержки JS? Вам нужно было бы сделать SPA - красиво, быстро и современно. Фреймы это изврат из прошлого века.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так организовать, как вариант: открывается первая страница и на ней начинается тикать таймер. На эту же страницу в iframe открывается одна из требуемых страниц, и соответсвенно все остальные переходы будут сделаны внутри iframe без перезагрузки первой страницы на которой тикает таймер.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, можно при первом появлении на странице, писать время в куку, а начиная со второго, открывать её с помощью JS, и вычислять разницу... time() от php очень бы пригодился)) По моему и в JS что-то подобное да есть. Возможно стоит зайти сюда javascript.ru или в поисковике набрать time js.

Comment: @Сергей Кашурин, я так и думал сделать. Только вот сейчас попробовал установить куку и ничего. Сделал как нагуглил:  
    document.cookie="timer=1234;";

Оказывается, куки без сервера все же не работают. Сделал файл 1.html просто на диске и открыл - не создается кука. Кинул в корень localhost - работает.  
Вариант с куками отпадает.

Comment: А как на счёт библиотек jQuery, они тоже отпадают? Ведь там есть замечательная библиотека, которая как раз и работает с cookie

Comment: +как вариант CSS3 HTML5, смотрите пример под 13 номером "13. Храним заметки с помощью CSS3" на сайте http://originalip.ru/?L=49

Comment: @сергей кашурин, локальные файлы открываются с адресом:  

    file:///C:/some_file.html
нет домена который надо связать с кукой, localStorage тоже не поможет. Пример 13 дает ошибку 404

Comment: @Сергей Кашурин, нужно отправлять архивом 4 страницы. HTML5 отмели за существованием юзеров с IE6,7 и пр. А с jQuery, я так понял тоже не будет работать. Куки без сервера невозможны наверно.  
Вариант с фреймом очень даже неплох. Даже от перегрузок страниц избавились)

Comment: Уф... и правда не работают)) Будь оригинален) сделай им gif анимацию)) Пусть радуются жизни...

Answer (score 3):

Я как-то делал автономную оффлайн систему для ЕГЭ тестирования на JS — её на DVD к книге прилагали.

В куках хранил пройденные вопросы и введённые ответы. Таймер в "основной" странице. А вопросы [подгружаются динамически](http://api.jquery.com/load/) - не в iFrame, просто в div'ы.

Comment: @sergiks, a как Вы заставили работать куки? У меня что-то без сервера не получилось.

Comment: [Чистым Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp), или плагином [`jQuery.cookie`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Comment: @sergiks, работало без сервера? Мне нужно, чтоб файлы открывались:     file:///C:/some_file.html

Comment: именно так и работало.

Comment: @sergiks, хм. Интересно почему у меня тогда куки не создавались так, а на сервере норм.

Comment: Протестировал в разных браузерах такой файл  

    file:///C:/denwer/home/localhost/www/test.html
с содержимым  

    <html>
        <head>
            <script> 
                document.cookie="username=test; expires=15/02/2015 00:00:00;";
                alert(document.cookie);
            </script>
        </head> 
    </html>
В следующих браузерах выводится все нормально (все браузеры последних версий):  
Opera, Firefox, Safari, Internet Explorer
Все они думают, что сайт в домене localhost.  
И только Chrome выводит пустое значение, то есть куки не установились.

Comment: @ReinRaus, аха блин, я неудачник. Только в хроме и пробовал((  
П.С. Внизу ответил как сделал в итоге. Просто iframe не подошли, т.к. страницы пихаются в какую-то программу, которая не знает iframe.

Comment: Chrome [не поддерживает куки для file:///...](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=535), если только не запустить его с флагом `--enable-file-cookies`. Альтернатива - использовать [html5 localStorage](http://paperkilledrock.com/2010/05/html5-localstorage-part-one/).

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел замену кукам, которая работает на локалке без сервера.

```
localStorage.setItem('ключ', 'значение'); // Назначение
localStorage.getItem('ключ'); // значение 
localStorage.clear(); // стереть все
```

Comment: В вопросе упоминаются старые браузеры, в них это не прокатит

Comment: Жаль. А хотелось бы)

Answer (score 0):

Если что, сделал через GET-параметры. На линках добавлял время оставшееся и повесил это на onclick по ссылкам.

Answer (score 0):

Если страницы открываются в одной вкладке, то можно использовать `window.name`.